# Relative path syntax for going up one level then down again in another

Tags: php

Currently there is a folder structure like so:

```
views - components - aside.php
      - sections - feature.php
```

In feature.php i want to include the aside.php so i would have thought this would have done it:

```
    <?php include '../components/aside.php'; ?>
```

I'm either missing something really obvious or theres better PHP syntax to find relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the path relative to the including file's path.

```
include __DIR__ . '/../components/aside.php';
```